# Extensions hidden on chrome://extension until inspect element?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

So I have a working manifest.json that runs a content script on chrome://extensions and the content script that does this:

```
"document.getElementById("joodangkbfjnajiiifokapkpmhfnpleo").remove();"
```

I have the flag for running extensions on chrome:// urls enabled and I know the manifest.json works because if I make my content script do something like change the background, on chrome://extension, it does.

I don't know how to easily explain this, but when I run the script mentioned above in the chrome console after I reset the page, it says that there isn't any element by that ID. That is until I inspect element on the extensions, then it isn't null. It's almost as if the element doesn't exist until I inspect element on it. It doesn't make sense to me, however, because I know it obviously exists due to me being able to see it. I hope I explained this well, anyone know why this happens and how I can make my script work?

Comment: The page is constructed dynamically. Use a MutationObserver or setTimeout. It's inside an iframe as well so you'll need to get it first.

Comment: @wOxxOm Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, the elements stay hidden until I actively inspect it, meaning that there is no active change with time so MutationObserver and setTimeout as I understand it won't work. I also don't know what you mean by "get it first", can you link something or explain please since I couldn't find anything on it. Thanks again for your help :)

Comment: The main page contains an iframe which contains the element you want. [Javascript - Get element from within an iFrame](//stackoverflow.com/q/1088544)